# PHP - SOAP 1.1 request and response handling in php

Tags: php, soap

I am trying to integrate netForum. It needs some SOAP requests. The following is a sample SOAP 1.1 request and response, but i don't know how to implement this in php.

Request:

```
POST /xweb/netFORUMXMLONDemand.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: nftpsandbox.avectra.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://www.avectra.com/OnDemand/2005/NewIndividualInformation"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <AuthorizationToken xmlns="http://www.avectra.com/OnDemand/2005/">
      <Token>string</Token>
    </AuthorizationToken>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <NewIndividualInformation xmlns="http://www.avectra.com/OnDemand/2005/">
      <oNode>xml</oNode>
    </NewIndividualInformation>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Response -

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <AuthorizationToken xmlns="http://www.avectra.com/OnDemand/2005/">
      <Token>string</Token>
    </AuthorizationToken>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <NewIndividualInformationResponse xmlns="http://www.avectra.com/OnDemand/2005/">
      <NewIndividualInformationResult>xml</NewIndividualInformationResult>
    </NewIndividualInformationResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Googling "PHP SOAP tutorial" gives quite a few results. This one would probably be a good start. http://www.w3schools.com/soap/default.asp

Answer (score 1):

PHP has built-in support for this through the SOAP extension (activated in most recent configs). The background behind this is available through http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php. SOAP lets you perform remote calls as if you were performing them on your own objects so you will probably have little to do with the *raw* data you're posting.

Basically the functions of PHP's SOAP extensions are split into a `SoapClient` class and a `SoapServer` class. The former will be the one you're going to need. Have a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.dorequest.php and check the API docs for what kind of requests you can make.